# android textview does not show after setting visible from another thread

Tags: android, multithreading, visibility, textview

I am having problems making my `TextViews` visible from another thread using the method `showDisclaimer()`. I have used `runOnUiThread()` to set the visibility of my `TextView`s. Basically, I want to show these views after importing the csv to the database. Can you take a look and see what I missed?

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

final static int INDEX_ACCTTYPE = 0; 
final static int INDEX_ECN = 1; 
final static int INDEX_TLN = 2; 
final static int INDEX_SIN = 3; 
final static int INDEX_MOBILE = 4; 
final static int INDEX_CITY = 5;
final static int INDEX_START_DATE = 6;
final static int INDEX_START_TIME = 7;
final static int INDEX_END_DATE = 8; 
final static int INDEX_END_TIME = 9; 
final static int INDEX_REASON = 10;
final static int INDEX_DETAILS = 11;

DatabaseHandler db;
String str;
ProgressDialog pd;

final private String csvFile = "http://www.meralco.com.ph/pdf/pms/pms_test.csv";
final private String uploadDateFile = "http://www.meralco.com.ph/pdf/pms/UploadDate_test.txt";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView homeText1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text1);
    TextView homeText2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text2);
    TextView homeText3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text3);
    TextView homeText4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text4);

    homeText1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    homeText2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    homeText3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    homeText4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    //db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

    if(dbExists()){
        db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
        Log.d("Count", "" + db.count());

        if(!uploadDateEqualsDateInFile())
            promptOptionalUpdate("There is a new schedule");
        showDisclaimer();
        Log.i("oncreate", "finished!");
        return;
    }

    promptRequiredUpdate("Schedule not updated");
    //showDisclaimer();
    Log.i("oncreate", "finished!");

}

public void promptOptionalUpdate(String Message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    builder.setMessage(Message)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Update Now",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Log.d("SHOW ALERT -->!", "update");
                            dropOldSchedule();
                            triggerDownload();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Later",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Log.d("SHOW ALERT -->!", "cancel");
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public void dropOldSchedule(){
    //TODO drop old schedule
}

public void triggerDownload() {

    if (!checkInternet()) {
        showAlert("An internet connection is required to perform an update, please check that you are connected to the internet");
        return;
    }

    if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Downloading schedule", 
            "This may take a few minutes...", true, false);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            db = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);
            db.beginTransaction();

            try {
                URL myURL = new URL(csvFile);

                BufferedReader so = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream()));
                while (true) {
                    String output = so.readLine();
                    if (output != null) {
                        String[] sched = output.split(",");
                        try {
                            db.addRow(sched[INDEX_SIN], sched[INDEX_CITY], 
                                    sched[INDEX_START_DATE], sched[INDEX_START_TIME], 
                                    sched[INDEX_END_DATE], sched[INDEX_END_TIME], 
                                    sched[INDEX_DETAILS], sched[INDEX_REASON]);
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                            db.addRow(sched[INDEX_SIN], sched[INDEX_CITY], 
                                    sched[INDEX_START_DATE], sched[INDEX_START_TIME], 
                                    sched[INDEX_END_DATE], sched[INDEX_END_TIME], 
                                    "", sched[INDEX_REASON]);
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                so.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                db.endTransaction();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                db.endTransaction();
            } 
            Log.d("Count", ""+db.count());
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (!pd.isShowing());

                    getUploadDate();
                    writeUploadDateInTextFile();
                    showDisclaimer();

                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

    });
    thread.start();

    //while(thread.isAlive());

    Log.d("triggerDownload", "thread died, finished dl. showing disclaimer...");

}

public void getUploadDate() {
    Log.d("getUploadDate", "getting upload date of schedule");

    if(pd!=null && pd.isShowing()) pd.dismiss();
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Getting upload date", 
            "This may take a few minutes...", true, false);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                URL myURL = new URL(uploadDateFile);

                BufferedReader so = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURL.openStream()));
                while (true) {
                    String output = so.readLine();
                    if (output != null) {
                        str = output;
                    }
                    else {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            so.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (!pd.isShowing());
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

        });
    thread.start();

    while (thread.isAlive());

    Log.d("getUploadDate","thread died, upload date="+str);
}

public void writeUploadDateInTextFile() {
    Log.d("writeUploadDateTextFile", "writing:"+str);

    try {
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                "update.txt", 0));
        out.write(str);
        out.close();
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showDisclaimer() {
    Log.d("ShowDisclaimer", "showing disclaimer");


    TextView homeText1x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text1);
    TextView homeText2x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text2);
    TextView homeText3x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text3);
    TextView homeText4x = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.home_text4);

    homeText3x
    .setText("You may view the schedule of pre-arranged power interruptions by clicking any of these buttons : SIN, City or Date. " +
            "The schedule has been updated as of " + str
            + ". Meralco is exerting all efforts to restore electric service as scheduled." +
            " The schedule, however, may change without further notice. For verification, follow-ups, or " +
            "latest updates, please contact our CALL CENTER through telephone nos. 16211, " +
            "fax nos. 1622-8554/1622-8556 or email address callcenter.tech.assist@meralco.com.ph.");


    homeText1x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    homeText2x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    homeText3x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    homeText4x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Log.d("ShowDisclaimer", "finished showing disclaimer");

}

public void promptRequiredUpdate(String Message) {
    Log.d("required update","required!");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    builder.setMessage(Message)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Update Now",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.d("SHOW ALERT -->!", "update");
            triggerDownload();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Later",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                Log.d("SHOW ALERT -->!", "cancel");
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public boolean uploadDateEqualsDateInFile() {
    Log.d("uploadDateEqualsDateInFile","comparing schedule upload dates");

    getUploadDate();

    try {
        String recordedDate = "";
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("update.txt");
        if (instream != null) { // if file the available for reading
            Log.d("uploadDateEqualsDateInFile","update.txt found!");

            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

            String line = null;
            while ((line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {
                recordedDate = line;
                Log.d("uploadDateEqualsDateInFile","recorded:"+recordedDate);
            }

            Log.d("uploadDateEqualsDateInFile","last upload date: " + str + ", recorded:" +recordedDate);

            if(str.equals(recordedDate)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        Log.d("uploadDateEqualsDateInFile","update.txt is null!");
        return false;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

}

public void showAlert(String Message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
    builder.setMessage(Message).setCancelable(false)
            .setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

public boolean checkInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo infos[] = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();

    for (NetworkInfo info : infos)
        if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING) {
            return true;
        }

    return false;
}

public boolean dbExists() {

    File database=getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHandler.DATABASE_NAME);

    if (!database.exists()) {
        Log.i("Database", "Not Found");
        return false;
    }

    Log.i("Database", "Found");
    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: R u getting any exceptions? or try AsyncTask or Handler in place of Thread.

Comment: @Anieeh No exceptions at all... but I noticed that after the call  to `showDisclaimer` (when everything seems to be finished), when I press the back button, the app crashes when supposedly it'll exit the app... I don't know if this observation helps...

Comment: So can u tell me what exception it is printing on the log on pressing back button?

Comment: again, no exceptions.. logcat only displays this: `07-30 15:20:16.439: I/dalvikvm(23482): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
07-30 15:20:16.689: D/dalvikvm(23482): JIT unchain all for threadid=1
07-30 15:20:16.699: I/dalvikvm(23482): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'`

Answer (score 0):

simplymoody, do what Chirag Raval suggested by declaring private static TextView homeText1, globally and in your onCreate initialise them. However, you should always update the UI from the main thread. But showDisclaimer() is still running on the background thread, so you could run the showDisclaimer() a couple of different ways. One would be to do what you have done in getUploadDate():

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               showDisclaimer()
            }
        });
```

Or you could use a handler:

```
private Handler showDisclaimerHandler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
homeText3x.setText("TEXT");


homeText1x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
homeText2x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
homeText3x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
homeText4x.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Log.d("ShowDisclaimer", "finished showing disclaimer");



return false;
}
});
```

And everywhere in a background thread you wish to run your showDisclaimer(), instead you run:

```
showDisclaimerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: Hi @digiphd, `showDisclaimer` is always called on the UI thread. I have problems on the call from `triggerDownload`. It was running on the UI thread. Believe me, I tried declaring them globally, static and not. Still didn't work..

Comment: However, I'll try your handler... Thank you!